# Featured Gallery to custom post type

Tags: metabox

I want to show Featured Gallery metabox in my custom post type. I have it only in article page, and i want to add it to my custom post type. How i can do it ? I tried with this, but not work :

```
function gallery_metabox( $types ) {
    $types[] = 'projects';
    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'gallery_metabox_post_types', 'gallery_metabox' );
```

Comment: WordPress doesn’t have a gallery meta box. Are you using a plugin? You’ll need to ask it’s author.

Comment: Yes in post page I have the "Featured Gallery" where i can select multiple images to show in post.

Comment: This isn't something from WordPress itself. Either your theme or a plugin adds it. Since 3rd-party themes and plugins are off topic here you'll need to contact the author.